"to be born" in a non-future context
I've been only familiar with using "to be" to describe future events, but then I came across the following sentence:

The first giant panda to be born in South Korea has been given quite the send-off. Thousands of people turned out to say emotional goodbyes to Fu Bao as she made her way from the Everland theme park in Yongin, South Korea to join a breeding programme in China. (BBC News Instagram post)

In this instance, the panda, Fu Bao, born in 2020 in South Korea, was just sent back to China. What's the usage of "to be born" in the sentence? Shouldn't it be something like "that was born" or simply "born"?
Furthering my research, I discovered another sentence that appears to employ a similar usage:

The modern men’s perm is loud for a hairstyle so soft. On TikTok, the hashtag #menperm, referring to one of the latest hair trends to be born from the app, has garnered more than 20.7 million views. (The NYT)

Does this usage align with the example provided earlier? If so, could anyone elaborate on the usage?

There's nothing exceptional about 'the first... to be born'. The same construction can be used with many verbs. "Roger Bannister was the first athlete to run a mile in less than four minutes."

the infinitive of run is to run, the infinitive of be born it to be born. They are not parallel.

You can use the to-infinitive to describe future events, but not every to-infinitive describes a future event - specifically, the construction that describes future events is be + to-infinitive:

My child is to be born next year.
The order was to be determined by drawing lots. (describing an event that was in the future at some past point in time)
He is to get his promotion soon. (the following verb doesn't have to be "to be", although it's common to use this construction with a passive voice)

The usage of "to" with phrases like "the first", "the second", "the last", etc. is a different usage, and does not imply a future tense on its own - instead, the tense is determined by the main verb of the sentence:

Neil Armstrong was the first human to walk on the surface of the moon.
If he wins, he will be the first to achieve a 300-win streak.
The more expensive TV was the first to break.

And yes, you can replace the to-infinitive in this case with "that" (or "who") and a past participle:

The more expensive TV was the first that broke.


Many people would insist on Neil Armstrong was the first human who walked on the surface of the moon.

Fair point - I've changed the example to something less questionable.

You might also address the fact that "to be born" in the question is a construction of the infinitive using the passive voice.

@JedSchaaf: "To be born" was originally the passive-voice counterpart of "to bear", but I think nowadays it's become an idiom, largely divorced from that origin. For example, we say "He was born to an Irish woman", not "He was born by an Irish woman." (To be sure, the passive-voice counterpart of "to bear" is still the same, except that it's now spelled "to be borne"; but the relevant sense of "to bear" is borderline-archaic, whereas the idiom "to be born" is still very common, even in the most casual speech.)

The verb for a baby arriving in this world:
to be born, infinitive=the only way to state the infinitive for a birth in English using a verb. The verb to be plus the past participle.

I was born in December.
I was lucky I was born in that month.
I was lucky to be born in that month.
Babies [who are] born in December are lucky.
Babies are born every day with those characteristics.
A baby is born every minute with brown eyes.

Basically, the second and third sentences mean the same thing.
Other tenses may sometimes be used: has/have been born, was/were being born, had been born, etc. All are formed with an auxiliary + be and the past participle.

@MishaLavrov Sure, just fast typing.

This does not answser the question, which was about why the infinitive was used: the OP assumed that this was "infinitive of purpose"; but Maciej's answer explains that it is a different use of the infinitive with the first.

The explanation comes from it being an infinitive and defective. To run, infinitive for run, To be born, infinitive for be born. She says "be+ to-infinitive describes future events". to be born can be embedded in past tense. I was lucky to be born in December. to be born is not a to infinitive.
